# How To Sharpen Image Using opencv In C

Tags: c, image, opencv

I tried to sharpen an image with OpenCV, but I found only functions for C++ and not for C, Someone knows how to sharpen an image in C (with OpenCV)?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately the [C API of OpenCV is **dead**](https://answers.opencv.org/question/185693/is-c-api-alive-or-not/). You can only call newest OpenCV from C++. I.e. the answer is "you can't, you must use C++ to write a new C wrapper for OpenCV".